# Rollback transactions in JAX-RS

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, transactions, jax-rs

I have a simple resource class that implements some POST method. How to *rollback* transaction if there was exceptions in my methods, and *commit* - if all is ok?

Is there a way to write this code once - not in every resource class that I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a dependency-injection will greatly simplify this. Using `@Transactional` or similar annotations around the methods where you want to commit/rollback transactions.

If you have to do this manually, you have basically two options:

- do it manually for every operation
- use the [proxy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern)/[decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and proxy/decorate all your classes that require transactions. Then in the proxy/decorator start the transaction, delegate to the target, and commit it after it returns. (this is how DI frameworks do it)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring, @Transactional will handle your scenario.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html